# Node.js url.parse result back to string

Tags: url, node.js

I am trying to do some simple pagination.
To that end, I'm trying to parse the current URL, then produce links to the same query, but with incremented and decremented `page` parameters.

I've tried doing the following, but it produces the same link, without the new `page` parameter.

```
var parts = url.parse(req.url, true);
parts.query['page'] = 25;
console.log("Link: ", url.format(parts));
```

The [documentation for the URL module](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.3.1/api/url.html) seems to suggest that `format` is what I need but I'm doing something wrong.

I know I could iterate and build up the string manually, but I was hoping there's an existing method for this.

Comment: Yes. I'll reformat it to JS to make it more standard for people to help out with.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

If you look at the [latest documentation](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/url.html), you can see that `url.format` behaves in the following way:

> - `search` will be used in place of `query`
> - `query` (object; see querystring) will only be used if `search` is absent.

And when you modify `query`, `search` remains unchanged and it uses it. So to force it to use `query`, simply remove `search` from the object:

```
var url = require("url");
var parts = url.parse("http://test.com?page=25&foo=bar", true);
parts.query.page++;
delete parts.search;
console.log(url.format(parts)); //http://test.com/?page=26&foo=bar
```

Make sure you're always reading the latest version of the documentation, this will save you a lot of trouble.

Comment: This is a good answer, I would consider anyone using it to _not_ use the delete operator as it is _really_ slow.

Comment: Prime example of premature optimization there buddy

Comment: I did not ask you to change the answer, I left a comment. _delete_ is 1000% slower than setting to null or undefined and makes no sense in objects anyway (what does it even _mean_ to remove an object's property, that makes no sense in OO design). In my opinion, setting it to undefined makes _much_ more sense, it still has the property, it is just not defined any more.

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to come off as aggressive. You are right, if someone is doing something where speed is critical, they might not want to use `delete`. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: You can always just set it to undefined. Note, that setting to null will throw an error in this case. Also note, that the docs for the url module are hard to read and strangely there are no examples. ;) Note #3: see  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14967535/delete-a-x-vs-a-x-undefined for 'delete' vs 'assign it to undefined' :)

Comment: Prefer `delete` over `setting it to undefined`. If later on you will want to copy the object, undefined will overwrite the existing one, like this `{...{search: "searching"}, ...{search: undefined}}`

Comment: using delete throws a linter error for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63702057 my use case works fine setting the object to undefined.

Answer (score 3):

Seems to me like it's a bug in node. You might try

```
// in requires
var url = require('url');
var qs = require('querystring');

// later
var parts = url.parse(req.url, true);
parts.query['page'] = 25;
parts.query = qs.stringify(parts.query);
console.log("Link: ", url.format(parts));
```

Comment: It's not a bug, it's clearly documented: http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/url.html

Comment: You're right, but isn't the latest version unstable? I only checked documentation for 0.4.12

Comment: Indeed, but the documentation has improved, and luckily for us, in this case, is consistent with older versions.

Comment: Is is still querystring or changed to require('qs')

Comment: `qs` if you want visionmedia's [query string parser](https://github.com/visionmedia/node-querystring), `querystring` for nodejs native parser.

Answer (score 2):

The other answer is good, but you could also do something like this. The `querystring` module is used to work with query strings.

```
var querystring = require('querystring');
var qs = querystring.parse(parts.query);
qs.page = 25;
parts.search = '?' + querystring.stringify(qs);
var newUrl = url.format(parts);
```

Comment: parts.query will be an Object if url.parse(..., true) is sent. http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.12/api/url.html#url.parse

Comment: you're right. This will work if url.parse(req.url) is used,  without the last parameter

Answer (score 0):

To dry out code and get at URL variables without needing to require('url') I used:

```
/* 
   Used the url module to parse and place the parameters into req.urlparams.
   Follows the same pattern used for swagger API path variables that load 
   into the req.params scope.

*/
  app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var url = require('url');
    var queryURL = url.parse(req.url, true);
    req.urlparams = queryURL.query;
    next();
  });

var myID = req.urlparams.myID;
```

This will parse and move the url variables into the req.urlparams variable. It runs early in the request workflow so is available for all expressjs paths.