# delete a.x vs a.x = undefined

Tags: javascript

Is there any substantial difference in doing either of these?

```
delete a.x;
```

vs

```
a.x = undefined;
```

where

```
a = {
    x: 'boo'
};
```

could it be said that they are equivalent?

(I'm not taking into account stuff like ["V8 likes not using `delete` better"](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/11/05/writing-fast-memory-efficient-javascript/))

Comment: The delete operator removes a property entirely. Setting a property to undefined removes the value. Setting a property to null changes the value to the null value. Here's a perf test if you like: http://jsperf.com/delete-vs-undefined-vs-null/3

Comment: @j08691 Nit: It doesn't remove the value. It assigns `undefined` as the value, which is still a ..

Comment: You should talk about why you care about this, then the answer can cater to your actual problem.

Answer (score 237, accepted):

They are not equivalent. The main difference is that setting

```
a.x = undefined
```

means that `a.hasOwnProperty("x")` will still return true, and therefore, it will still show up in a `for in` loop, and in `Object.keys()`. Whereas

```
delete a.x
```

means that `a.hasOwnProperty("x")` will return false

You can't tell if a property exists by testing

```
if (a.x === undefined)
```

If you are trying to determine if a property exists, you should always use

```
// If you want inherited properties
if ('x' in a)

// If you don't want inherited properties
if (a.hasOwnProperty('x'))
```

**Following the prototype chain** (mentioned by [zzzzBov](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14967535/delete-a-x-vs-a-x-undefined/14967568#answer-14967572)) Calling `delete` will allow it to go up the prototype chain, whereas setting the value to undefined will not look for the property in the chained prototypes

```js
var obj = {
  x: "fromPrototype"
};
var extended = Object.create(obj);
extended.x = "overriding";
console.log(extended.x); // overriding
extended.x = undefined;
console.log(extended.x); // undefined
delete extended.x;
console.log(extended.x); // fromPrototype
```

**Deleting Inherited Properties** If the property you are trying to delete is inherited, `delete` will not affect it. That is, `delete` only deletes properties from the object itself, not inherited properties.

```js
var obj = {x: "fromPrototype"};
var extended = Object.create(obj);
delete extended.x;
console.log(extended.x); // Still fromPrototype
```

Therefore, if you need to make sure an object's value will be undefined, `delete` will not work when the property is inherited, you will have to set (override) it to `undefined` in that case. Unless the place that is checking for it will use `hasOwnProperty`, but it likely wouldn't be safe to assume that everywhere that checks it will use `hasOwnProperty`

Comment: `"x" in a` will also return `true` with the former, and `false` with the latter. The output of `Object.keys` will also be different.

Comment: why do you state that I shouldn't check for undefined? seems reasonable enough to me.

Comment: @Nico Because that won't tell you if a property exists. I'm not saying don't ever use it. But if you're checking for `undefined`, you may as well just check `if (a.x)`, unless it's for numbers and 0 is valid

Answer (score 38):

To paraphrase the question:

> Are `delete a.x` and `a.x = undefined` equivalent?

## No.

The former removes the key from the variable, the later sets the key with a value of `undefined`. This makes a difference when iterating over properties of objects, and when `hasOwnProperty` is used.

```
a = {
    x: true
};
a.x = undefined;
a.hasOwnProperty('x'); //true
delete a.x;
a.hasOwnProperty('x'); //false
```

Additionally, this will make a significant difference when the prototype chain is involved.

```
function Foo() {
    this.x = 'instance';
}
Foo.prototype = {
    x: 'prototype'
};
a = new Foo();
console.log(a.x); //'instance'

a.x = undefined;
console.log(a.x); //undefined

delete a.x;
console.log(a.x); //'prototype'
```

Comment: +1 Great point about `delete` allowing it to go up the prototype chain

Answer (score 8):

If `a.x` is a setter function, `a.x = undefined` will call the function whereas `delete a.x` will not call the function.

Comment: But will it delete the function?

Comment: "delete a.x" would remove the function (i.e. "remove property x from object a") whereas "a.x = undefined" would not remove the function (i.e. "use setter x on object a with an input argument of undefined")

Comment: You could add that to the answer. Instead of "will not call the function" should say "will not call the function, but will delete it instead".

Answer (score 4):

Using an array, instead of an object, I can showcase that delete uses less heap memory than undefined.

For example, this code will not finish:

```
let y = 1;
let ary = [];
console.log("Fatal Error Coming Soon");
while (y < 4294967295)
{
    ary.push(y);
    ary[y] = undefined;
    y += 1;
}
console(ary.length);
```

It produces this error:

```
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory.
```

So, as you can see `undefined` actually takes up heap memory.

However, if you also `delete` the ary-item (instead of just setting it to `undefined`), the code will slowly finish:

```
let x = 1;
let ary = [];
console.log("This will take a while, but it will eventually finish successfully.");
while (x < 4294967295)
{
    ary.push(x);
    ary[x] = undefined;
    delete ary[x];
    x += 1;
}
console.log(`Success, array-length: ${ary.length}.`);
```

These are extreme examples, but they make a point about `delete` that I haven't seen anyone mention anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is a difference.
If you use `delete a.x` the x isn't any more a property of a, but if you use `a.x=undefined` it is a property but its value is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

The names are a little confusing. `a.x = undefined` just sets the property to `undefined`, but the property is still there:

```
> var a = {x: 3};
> a.x = undefined;
> a.constructor.keys(a)
["x"]
```

`delete` actually deletes it:

```
> var a = {x: 3};
> delete a.x;
> a.constructor.keys(a)
[]
```

Answer (score 1):

This REPL from node should illustrate the difference.

```
> a={ x: 'foo' };
{ x: 'foo' }
> for (var i in a) { console.log(i); };
x
undefined
> a.x=undefined;
undefined
> for (var i in a) { console.log(i); };
x
undefined
> delete a.x;
true
> for (var i in a) { console.log(i); };
undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you can see the difference between `var o1 = {p:undefined};` and `var o2 = {};`.

In both cases, `o.p` will be `undefined` but in the first case, it's because that's the *value* and in the second case because *there is no value*.

`delete` is the operator that lets you get from `o1` (or another object that has a value assigned to its `p` property) to `o2` that way: `delete o1.p;`.

The reverse operation is made by simply assigning a value (`undefined` in this example but it could be something else) to the property `o1.p = undefined;`.

So **no**, they are not equivalent.

---

`delete o.p;` will

- remove the property `p` from the object if it has one
- do nothing otherwise

`o.p = undefined;` will

- add a property `p` to the object if it doesn't have one yet and set its value to `undefined`
- simply change the value of the property if the object already has it

---

From a performance perspective, `delete` is *bad* because it *modifies the structure of the object* (just like adding a new property if you haven't initialized it in the constructor).

Whereas setting the value to `undefined` releases the content as well but without forcing to modify the structure.

Answer (score 1):

Object is simply a tree representation, that means, in memory the root points to various memory locations where keys of that object are stored. and that location points to another location where the actual value of that key is stored, or locations where the child keys are stored or locations where the array values are stored.

When you delete any key from an object using delete, actually it deletes link between that key and its parent object and the memory locations of key and its value are freed up to store another information.

When you try to delete any key by setting undefined as its value, then you are just setting its value, not deleting that key. That means that keys memory location is still linked with its parent object and the value if key is undefined.

Using undefined instead of using delete keyword is a bad practice, as it doesn't release memory location of that key.

Even if the key is not present, and you set it as undefined, then that key will get created with value `undefined`.

e.g.

```
var a = {};
a.d = undefined;
console.log(a); // this will print { d: undefined }
```

delete can't be worked with inherited properties because that property is not the part of that child object.

Comment: Note that newer engines prefer you don't delete keys, because when you do the engine needs to create a new class for it and update it wherever the "class" was referenced.

Comment: @JuanMendes, Can you give any reference please.

Comment: See [Does using delete keyword affect v8 optimizations of an object?](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/v8-users/zE4cOHBkAnY) TL;DR `as a general rule of thumb, using 'delete' makes thing slower.` and https://developers.google.com/v8/design `To reduce the time required to access JavaScript properties, V8 does not use dynamic lookup to access properties. Instead, V8 dynamically creates hidden classes behind the scenes. In V8, an object changes its hidden class when a new property is added.` , and finally https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/11/writing-fast-memory-efficient-javascript/