# Since getData() is deprecated for JSONModel in SAPUI5 1.34 then how to fetch/Update the Model?

Tags: json, sapui5, javascript-objects

Since getData() is deprecated for JSONModel in SAPUI5 1.34, from

```
oModel.getProperty("/")
```

I am getting all the Objects(my Model returns object in [Objects Objects] format).
Want to know how to delete a partcular object and update the same in my Model(oModel).

Please also let me know if I am fetching data from oModel correctly?

Comment: Where does it say getData is deprecated? API says getData is still supported for JSON Model.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `oModel.getProperty("/")` is the way to go.

You cannot directly delete a property of an object with the JSONModel in a matter that updates all bindings:

1. You could set the property to undefined with  `oModel.setProperty("/Path/To/Object/To/Delete", undefined)`
2. You can get the parent object, delete the property and reassign the changed object to update all bindings:

```js
var obj = oModel.getProperty("/Path/To/Object/To");
delete obj.Delete;
oModel.setProperty("/Path/To/Object/To", obj);
```

As you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14967535/delete-a-x-vs-a-x-undefined) assigning undefined is not the same as deleting a property.