# Difference between assigning an object to undefined and delete

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I was reading Secrets of the JavaScript Ninja and came across a coding example:

```
var ninja = {
    yell: function(n){
        return n > 0 ? ninja.yell(n-1) + "a" : "hiy";
    }
};

var samurai = { yell: ninja.yell };
//var ninja = {};
//delete ninja;
samurai.yell(4);
```

If I uncomment the second commented line, `samurai.yell(4)` runs fine, I understand it as `samurai` still has its reference to the function originally referenced by `ninja.yell`, which `delete` removed.

However, if I run the first commented line instead, `samurai.yell(4)` will give an error.

Can someone explain what's happening under the hood?

I thought if you assign `ninja` to be `undefined`, a new reference will be created and linked to `ninja`, the original reference is still there, and since `samurai` still has a reference to the function, garbage collection won't come along and delete it in memory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [delete a.x vs a.x = undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14967535/delete-a-x-vs-a-x-undefined)

Comment: Not a duplicate; this is all about how closures work, which is not at all referenced in the linked question.

Comment: See the **Following the prototype chain** and **Deleting Inherited Properties** parts of the accepted answer of the thread linked by @Weedoze

Comment: @pistou I read the thread, but I think it explains more about how 'delete' works than why 'ninja = {}' here will lead to an error. The thread only said this can remove the inherited properties but didn't explain why it works.

Comment: @pistou: This is not about prototypes or inheritance either, purely about scope and closures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked out @mrid and @Amadan's answers and thought a bit, I think I figured it out and came up with a simpler answer, and my explanation in my question is not entirely true.

If I uncomment the first commented line,

```
var ninja = {};
```

I'm assigning ninja to an empty object and consequently, I try to run "samurai.yell(4);", I get an error. The reason is because <s>**samurai** tries to find **ninja** through its "scope chain" (i.e. some closure magic, which it does find it, but when it tries to find if **ninja** has a property **yell**, it's gone, thus the error.</s> though **samurai** still holds a reference to that anonymous function (which implies it can still run that function), when that anonymous function tries to run `ninja.yell()`, it couldn't find it anymore, thus the error.

A way to fix this is of course, use the `this`,

```
var ninja = {
    yell: function (n) {
        return n > 0 ? this.yell(n-1) + "a" : "hiy";
    }
};

var samurai = { yell: ninja.yell };
var ninja = {};
samurai.yell(4);
```

Another way is to use a named function expression,

```
var ninja = {
    yell: function foo(n) {
        return n > 0 ? foo(n-1) + "a" : "hiy";
    }
};

var samurai = { yell: ninja.yell };
var ninja = {};
samurai.yell(4);
```

And everything should be working.

If I uncomment the second commented line,

```
delete ninja;
```

I'm actually not doing anything. **delete** is only for "removing" properties of an object (you can never delete anything in Javascript, garbage collection handles that), it returns true if the operation is successful, false otherwise. Therefore, "delete" doesn't work on **ninja**, so simply speaking, I'm not doing anything extra to **ninja** when I uncomment "delete ninja;", everything still works as normal.

Therefore, you can forget everything I said about "reference" and "delete" in my question, they're not relevant and not true.

Comment: `delete ninja` does something, just not to `ninja`, but to `window`. Otherwise, yes, pretty much.

Comment: I used `var` to declare ninja, so `ninja` is not a property of `window` but a variable. So `delete` still does nothing. @Amadan

Comment: `delete` does try to find if there exists a property `ninja` in the `window` object, then returns false. So @Amadan is not wrong.

Comment: @Amadan my explanation is still a bit wrong, `samurai` actually holds a direct reference to the function, why it won't work after `var ninja = {}` is because inside that function, it cannot access `ninja.yell` anymore. I have made some changes to my answer, this time it should be final.

Answer (score 3):

When you write

```
var ninja = {
yell: function(n){
    return n > 0 ? ninja.yell(n-1) + "a" : "hiy";
}
};

var samurai = { yell: ninja.yell };
var ninja = {};
//delete ninja;
samurai.yell(4);
```

`var ninja = {};` will declare a variable named `ninja`

the next line `samurai.yell(4);` will throw an error since ninja has been re-defined and the new object does not have any function named `yell` associated with it.

**Explanation :**

In the beginning, `ninja` is

```
var ninja = {
    yell: function(n){
        return n > 0 ? ninja.yell(n-1) + "a" : "hiy";
    }
};
```

Here ninja has a function `yell` inside it which can be called.

When you change it's value to

```
ninja = {};
```

The old value ( along with the function ) gets erased and overwritten with the new value.

Therefore, when you call

```
samurai.yell(4);
```

It goes to `{ yell: ninja.yell };` and since the new `ninja` doesn't have `yell` function, it throws an error

Comment: I tried losing the 'var' and used 'ninja = {}' instead, it still gives me the same error.

Comment: So what you're trying to say is instead of storing the reference in 'samurai.yell' directly to the function, whenever I run samurai.yell(4), samurai is actually finding its reference to 'yell', then access 'ninja', then try to find the property 'yell' through 'ninja'? And because of this and ninja is now an empty object, 'yell' can't be found, so... error? However, this contrasts my understanding of 'delete', as only for 'delete' to work, samurai has to store an reference to the function so when ninja is 'deleted', samurai can still run the 'yell' function. @mrid

Comment: That's what I was trying to explain. "samurai has to store an reference" - no, it stores the *binding*. When `ninja` is deleted, the closed-over binding remains. When `ninja` is replaced, the closed-over binding remains (but to something different, an empty object).

Comment: I thought about what you said a bit and I think I came up with sth simpler. @mrid

Answer (score 3):

As I said in comments, it's all about how closures work:

```js
var bar = 1;
var foo = function() { console.log(bar); } // closes over `bar`
foo(); // closed-over `bar` reference: 1
bar = 2;
foo(); // closed-over `bar` reference reflects the update: 2
delete bar;
foo(); // closed-over `bar` still references the same location,
       // even when current context no longer has it
```

You don't often see examples with `delete`, but it is this very mechanism that makes them useful as a replacement for private variables:

```js
var foo = (function() {
  var bar = 1;
  return function() {
    console.log(bar);
  };
})();

foo();            // closed-over `bar`: 1 - even though:
console.log(bar); // Uncaught ReferenceError, as
                  // `bar` is not available in local context
```

Comment: Why it refer to the same location even after deleting the object ?

Comment: I don't know how to answer that besides "that's the point of closures". They will keep the binding even if the property is deleted, even if the variable goes out of scope - they keep the bindings that were in effect when the closure was created. You can't make a closure forget a binding, except by letting the closure itself expire.

Comment: I should probably make my vocabulary a bit tighter. Closures capture their local environment, which consists of bindings. (Bindings are different from references.) When you delete a property `window.ninja`, you don't delete the binding that exists in the closure, and the closure is free to keep using it. When you assign a new value to `window.ninja`, you use the underlying `SetMutableBinding` operation, changing the value of an existent binding - thus, the closed-over environment reflects the change, and suddenly your function can't find `.yell` on it.

Comment: I think I understand your examples, your second example definitely will lead to an error since 'bar' is in the function scope of the IIFE, outer scope absolutely cannot access the 'bar' thus leads to an error, but can you elaborate more on why 'ninja = {}' will lead to an error? I'm still kinda confused, sorry...

Comment: Because the binding is still the same; when you replace `ninja`'s binding with `{}`, the `samurai.yell` closure will share this value, so when `samurai.yell` body is executing, it is now trying to find `.yell` on `{}`, which doesn't exist. The point of the second example wasn't to demonstrate that the outer context doesn't have access to `bar` - I'm sure you knew it already - but that despite `bar` being nonexistent in current context, the closure still does have access to it. Whether going out of scope or getting explicitly deleted from the current context, the closure will keep the bindings.

Comment: I thought about what you said a bit and I think I came up with sth simpler. @Amadan

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you understood it right, but the real reason for that is GC mechanics.

They are passing reference to the function itself, ninja.yell. That's because of garbage collection mechanism - until any references are alive, this function will not be collected.

In this particular case, we're grabbing reference to `ninja.yell`, and even if we delete object originally containing this function, it will not be garbage collected.

Mostly, such behavior is unwanted, that's why people usually avoid `delete` operator.