# How to reduce keys of hashes in an array?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

For example:
(I assume something like JSON data)

```
const arr = [
  {foo: 1, bar: 2, hoge: 3, fuga: 4},
  {foo: 1, bar: 2, hoge: 3, fuga: 4},
  {foo: 1, bar: 2, hoge: 3, fuga: 4},
  {foo: 1, bar: 2, hoge: 3, fuga: 4},...
]
```

I dont need `bar` and `fuga` keys,
So I wanna extract from this array like

```
[
  {foo: 1, hoge: 3},
  {foo: 1, hoge: 3},
  {foo: 1, hoge: 3},
  {foo: 1, hoge: 3},...
]
```

How can I do this in a simple way?

Comment: what have you tried? do you need the same objects, or just the key/value pairs?

Comment: thank you everyone, @Faly and @Nandu Kalidindi's method using `map` function is best for me! Cuz its written in one line.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need a separate array, you could simply delete those properties by iterating the array:

```js
const arr = [
  {foo: 1, bar: 2, hoge: 3, fuga: 4},
  {foo: 1, bar: 2, hoge: 3, fuga: 4},
  {foo: 1, bar: 2, hoge: 3, fuga: 4},
  {foo: 1, bar: 2, hoge: 3, fuga: 4}
];

arr.forEach(function(t) {
  delete t.bar;
  delete t.fuga;
});

console.log(arr);
```

As an alternative to `delete`, you could set those properties to `undefined` as well. [It is known to be somewhat faster](https://jsperf.com/delete-vs-undefined-vs-null/3), but note that [the two are not equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14967535/delete-a-x-vs-a-x-undefined#14967568).

```js
const arr = [
  {foo: 1, bar: 2, hoge: 3, fuga: 4},
  {foo: 1, bar: 2, hoge: 3, fuga: 4},
  {foo: 1, bar: 2, hoge: 3, fuga: 4},
  {foo: 1, bar: 2, hoge: 3, fuga: 4}
];

arr.forEach(function(t) {
   t.bar = undefined;
   t.fuga = undefined;
});

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `array.prototype.map` with some `destructuring` and `shorthand object litteral`:

```js
const arr = [
  {foo: 1, bar: 2, hoge: 3, fuga: 4},
  {foo: 1, bar: 2, hoge: 3, fuga: 4},
  {foo: 1, bar: 2, hoge: 3, fuga: 4},
  {foo: 1, bar: 2, hoge: 3, fuga: 4}
];

const res = arr.map(({foo, hoge}) => ({foo, hoge}));

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a mapper function that maps only the specified keys and returns the expected output. Almost similar to `_.pick`

```js
const mapper = ({foo, hoge}) => ({foo, hoge});

const arr = [
  {foo: 1, bar: 2, hoge: 3, fuga: 4},
  {foo: 1, bar: 2, hoge: 3, fuga: 4},
  {foo: 1, bar: 2, hoge: 3, fuga: 4},
  {foo: 1, bar: 2, hoge: 3, fuga: 4}
]

console.log(arr.map(mapper))
```

Comment: you could write `arr.map(mapper)`, too

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and return only the desired keys:

```js
const arr = [{
    foo: 1,
    bar: 2,
    hoge: 3,
    fuga: 4
  },
  {
    foo: 1,
    bar: 2,
    hoge: 3,
    fuga: 4
  },
  {
    foo: 1,
    bar: 2,
    hoge: 3,
    fuga: 4
  },
  {
    foo: 1,
    bar: 2,
    hoge: 3,
    fuga: 4
  }
];

const result = arr.map(item => ({
  foo: item.foo,
  hoge: item.hoge
}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) operator

```
arr.forEach(function(element) {
  delete element.bar;
  delete element.fuga;
});
```