# difference between this.some = undefined Vs delete this.some

Tags: javascript

Hey I was reading the documentation for [delete operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) and I couldn't see any significant performance difference (in most uses cases) between:

```
const myObj = {
    name: 'Juan',
    last: 'Molina'
};

delete myObj.last;    // myObj.last = undefined
console.log(myObj);   // {name: 'Juan'}
```

the only difference that I found was that delete command makes a distinction between own and chain properties but I think this is a specific situation.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14967535/delete-a-x-vs-a-x-undefined

Comment: So what's your question? `delete` completely *removes* the property, the other sets its value to `undefined`. There *is* a difference, though whether it's significant depends on what you do with it afterwards.

Comment: your question is a duplicate.
Have a look here :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14967535/delete-a-x-vs-a-x-undefined

Answer (score 0):

`delete` does what the name says: it deletes the property from the object.

In contrast to that, simply assigning `undefined` to that property **does not delete it**:

```js
const myObj = {
    name: 'Juan',
    last: 'Molina'
};

myObj.last = undefined
console.log(myObj);   // { "name": "Juan", "last": undefined }
```