# Delete a value from a Javascript Object which is retrieved from MongoDB

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb

I am well aware that this question has been already asked and answered multiple times however in my case I have absolutely no clue why my particualr key-value is not being deleted.

**index.js**

```
router.post('/user', function(req, res, next){
    User.findOne({'email': req.body.email}, function(err, user){
       //Few Functions here that perform Validation

        delete user['password'];
        console.log(user);
        res.json({'info': user});
    });
});
```

The above method does not delete the field of password. I have even used the method

```
delete user.password
```

However in my Javascript Object the field is yet present.My Javscript Object is a JSON Object and has the following structure:

```
{
  username: 'username1',
  desc: 'Hello ! Welcome to your Profile Page. You can edit your Bio whenever you want to.',
  verified: true,
  _id: id,
  firstName: 'FirstName',
  lastName: 'LastName',
  email: 'email@email.com',
  password: 'encryptedPassword',
  verifyEmailToken: '',
  publicId: 'publicID',
  phoneNo: '9xxxxxxxxx',
  profileImage: 'example.jpg',
  __v: 0
}
```

I have seen exmaples such as

```
let person = {
            name: "Harry",
            age: 16,
            gender: "Male"
        };
delete person.age;
```

And the Output comes as below in my console:

```
{ name: 'Harry', gender: 'Male' }
```

However in my case of the MongoDB `user` it is just not happening. There is no error also that is thrown. Does it have to do anything to do with Object Types ? Or am I missing something very small and insignificant ?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: console.log users and see the output

Comment: @MrKhan The output is given above. It remains unchanged with the password field yet present.

Comment: so you dont get password in the object. yet you try to use it as a key

Comment: @MrKhan I do get password in my object

Comment: what do you see if you console.log user.password after delete line

Comment: @MrKhan I was seeing the password field even after delete. I have updated the answer below. Please let me know your thoughts on that.

Comment: What is printed by `console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(user, 'password'))`?

Comment: @52d6c6af It is coming 'undefined'

Comment: In that case, the property does not exist directly on `user`. Try `console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(user.__proto__, 'password'))`

Comment: @52d6c6af I have found a method below. Check it and let me know what you think.

Comment: `findOne` has the optional  _projection_ parameter, which allows to _exclude_ fields you don't need in the returned document. You can use it, if it suits your application logic.

Comment: @prasad_ I have used `findOne` only.

Comment: @52d6c6af When I used `console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(user.__proto__, 'password'))` I got the following response

`{
  get: [Function: get],
  set: [Function: set],
  enumerable: true,
  configurable: true
}`

Comment: That means that `password` is on the prototype of `user`. That is why `delete user.password` does not work. `delete` operates on own properties, not properties on the prototype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so I went through the documentation of MongoDB for the query `db.collection.findOne(query, projection)` and found that the `findOne()` method returns a document rather than a cursor.

You can refer the docs https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne

Hence I had to convert it to raw JSON for the delete operation.

So I used

```
user.toJSON();
```

And then used the `delete` method on the Object which worked.

For example

```
  let json = user.toJSON();
  delete json['password'];
```

One can also use `toObject()` Method as shown below:

```
  let json = user.toObject();
  delete json['password'];
```

Answer (score 0):

The `__v` can infer the usage of mongoose.

Consider the following example:

```js
class A {
  props = { password: 'fff' }
  get password () {
    return this.props['password']
  }
}
const a = new A()
console.log('haspassword', a.password)
delete a.password
console.log('haspassword', a.password)
```

If e.g a getter is defined, then deleting will not be useful.

- you should try [set](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/document.html#document_Document-set)
  `user.set('password', undefined)`

or directly

`user.password = undefined`

---

edit as noticed by @52d6c6af 
More precision about why the [delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) operator may seem not to work (e.g when using mongoose model instances):

> If a property with the same name exists on the object's prototype chain, then, after deletion, the object will use the property from the prototype chain (in other words, delete only has an effect on own properties).

In case above, password is still listed because password is defined on the prototype (which happens because of the [get](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) syntax in a class)

> When using get the property will be defined on the instance's prototype, while using Object.defineProperty() the property will be defined on the instance it is applied to.

Comment: I thought of setting it as undefined however the issue is user.hasOwnProperty("password') and will still true and will show up in a for loop as mentionned out here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14967535/delete-a-x-vs-a-x-undefined

Comment: if you confirm it is indeed mongoose, you can simply take user.toJSON() and this time apply delete on it

Comment: Yes I just found that out while referring the docs and have placed it in the answer.

Comment: `delete` works with getter properties, as far as I know.

Comment: I am interested in your comment @52d6c6af but in posted snippet it does not. To which case are you referring to ?

Comment: OK, in your example it does not work because `.password` is defined on the prototype.

Comment: thanks for enlightment. However in case above password is not in ```OwnPropertyNames```, ```props``` is.

Comment: The reason `delete` does not work in your example is that `delete` operates on own properties. The fact that it is a getter is not really relevant.

Comment: I did not know about this behaviour, I will update post accordingly because it is indeed wrong, thanks for sharing that knowledge!