# Regex for Query String

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I had a regex function that I thought worked for removing the page variable in a querystring.  Right now it works fine if the variable isn't first, however if the variable is the first variable, it doesn't catch ?search=.

## Working Case:

```
http://blahblah.com/stuff/pages/things?search=somethingURIEncoded&page=2
```

turns into

```
console.log( req.url.replace(/&page(\=[^&]*)?(?=&|$)|^page(\=[^&]*)?(&|$)/, '') )
http://blahblah.com/stuff/pages/things?search=somethingURIEncoded
```

## Non-Working Case:

```
http://blahblah.com/stuff/pages/things?page=2&search=somethingURIEncoded
```

turns into

```
console.log( req.url.replace(/&page(\=[^&]*)?(?=&|$)|^page(\=[^&]*)?(&|$)/, '') )
http://blahblah.com/stuff/pages/things?page=2&search=somethingURIEncoded
```

Anyone know how to fix this regex I'm using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to parse a whole url, node.js has a built in [`url`](http://nodejs.org/api/url.html) module.

It has a parse method that seems to do what you need:

```
url.parse(urlStr, [parseQueryString], [slashesDenoteHost])
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7517332/node-js-url-parse-result-back-to-string) answers how to build it back into a URL if you'd like, and shows a usage example.

You also have a built-in [`querystring`](http://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html) module.

You can use `querystring.parse`

```
querystring.parse('foo=bar&baz=qux&baz=quux&corge')
// returns
{ foo: 'bar', baz: ['qux', 'quux'], corge: '' }
```

Comment: Much better than what I was doing before.  I'm pretty sure I'd tried this and it had failed for some reason, probably me not removing the search from the parsed URL.  Where I had two problems, I now have none.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `^page` it should be `\?page`, but of course you would have to replace the `?` back.  You can capture it and make all of the other groupings non-capture with `?:`.

Comment: It should be noted I have about zero applicable regex experience, other than stealing things from the internet.  Thanks for the help though!