# What is the logic behind the TypeScript error "The operand of a 'delete' operator must be optional"?

Tags: javascript, typescript

This is the new error that is coming in typescript code.

I am not able to realize the logic behind it
[Documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#operands-for-delete-must-be-optional)

```
/*When using the delete operator in strictNullChecks, 
the operand must now be any, unknown, never, or be optional 
(in that it contains undefined in the type). Otherwise, use of the delete operator is an error.*/

interface Thing {
  prop: string;
}

function f(x: Thing) {
  delete x.prop; // throws error = The operand of a 'delete' operator must be optional.
}
```

Comment: Your question includes the answer... `When using the delete operator in strictNullChecks, 
the operand must now be any, unknown, never, or be optional `

Answer (score 244, accepted):

> I am not able to realize the logic behind it

The logic as I understand is the following:

Interface `Thing` is a contract asking to have a (non-null, non-undefined) `prop` as a `string`.

If one removes the property, then the contract is not implemented anymore.

If you want it still valid when removed, just declare it as optional with a `?`: `prop?: string`

I'm actually surprised that this was not causing error in earlier versions of TypeScript.

Comment: This is a false positive in a case where you are using React and want to pass props to a component, but do not want to pass all the props to HTML DOM element as they are not valid and you are using a spread operator to allow consumer to pass all native HTML attributes. Then you make a copy of the props and delete the unnecessary props.

Comment: holy cow @toni_lehtimaki that is my EXACT situation... :)

Comment: It's also a false positive in cases where the prototype chain still includes the property - because the `delete` statement only works on direct properties, and not on inherited properties. You can do for example `delete node.getAttribute` on an `Element` and everything is fine - you may have deleted a property that was hiding the inherited property, but it still inherits `getAttribute` from the prototype.

Comment: I simply dont like it. I have to optimize a TS project with a lot of classes. It was made without strict mode enabled. After enabling it, I encountered this delete thingy. But I cannot make the props optional, because I have to do a ton of undefined checks then. Going back to non strict is not an option. I just wanna cry. Maybe sometime I will understand the benefits...

Comment: @aProgger Is your issue the false positives from some frameworks mentioned above or is that custom code? If the properties are _not_ optional, then what's the reason for using `delete`? Maybe there's an alternative.

Comment: @Pac0 It's custom. There is a lot of api communication like sending data to client who manipulates and sends it back to the server. The data send to the client is around a few MB and gets cached in the local storage of the browser. After manipulating, all non essential data gets deleted. There are a few KB left. These data will be stored into the DB. Of course I could let the server delete the non-essentials. But this is not wanted.

Comment: @aProgger At first sight I'd say some "clean" approach would be to have two types, the one with all the data, and a "light" version of it. May deserve it's own question with more details, though.

Comment: @Pac0 had the same idea and already implemented it. I made a (super-)class function which collects all the data and returns them as the new type.

Answer (score 97):

The logic behind of this, is that you need to implement your interface with an optional property like this:

```
interface Thing {
  prop?: string;
}
// OR
interface Thing {
  prop: string | undefined;
}

function f(x: Thing) {
  delete x.prop; 
}
```

So the interface's contract won't be broken.

Comment: only response that actually answered OPs question

Answer (score 30):

Maybe this can helpful

```
const { propToDelete, ...otherProps} = yourObject
return otherProps
```

with that you can use otherProps object without break out

Comment: Thanks. It helps me a lot. Seem like a hack, but a neat trick.

Answer (score 28):

### Quick fix

You could change the type of `x` to a partial:

```
function f(x: Partial<Thing>) {
  delete x.prop;
}
```

But I don't usually like to mutate (modify) objects which have been passed to me from possibly unknown code. So I would usually make a new object instead:

```
function f(x: Thing) {
  const y = { ...x } as Partial<Thing>;
  delete y.prop;
}
```

Since `Partial` makes all the properties optional, this will allow you to delete anything from `y`.

### Recommended

To be more specific, you could use [`PartialBy`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54178819/99777) (one liner) or [`SetOptional`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/type-fest/blob/main/source/set-optional.d.ts) (from type-fest):

```
  const y = { ...x } as PartialBy<Thing, 'prop1' | 'prop2'>;
```

That would make `prop1` and `prop2` optional but keep all other properties as they were originally.

### Alternative

Instead of making the properties optional in the type, we could completely remove them:

```
  const y = { ...x } as Partial<Thing>;
  delete y.prop1;
  delete y.prop2;
  const z = y as Omit<Thing, 'prop1' | 'prop2'>;
```

Let me know if you find a shorter way.

### Break the type constraints

If you *were* happy to mutate x, you could use:

```
delete (x as Partial<Thing>).prop1;
```

The `as` keyword is powerful but dangerous.  The type of x suggests that `prop1` should be present, and yet we now have an `x` with no `prop1` property.

### Note

Above, I wrote `const y = value as Type;` because I find it easier to read.  But you should probably use `const y: Type = value;` instead, because that does [better type checking](https://twitter.com/joeytwiddle/status/1562748208136486912).

Answer (score 9):

Another implementation if you want it to exist:

```
interface Thing {
  prop: string;
}
interface PropoptionalThing {
  prop?: string;
}

function f(x: Thing): PropoptionalThing {
  let tmp: PropoptionalThing = x;
  delete tmp.prop;
  return tmp;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The `prop` property in `Thing` interface must be mark as optional using `?` mark.

then your `Thing` interface must be like this.

```
interface Thing {
  prop?: string;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Use lodash omit

Use an optional parameter. If removing a prop is mandatory then you can make use of the below code.

```
const otherProps = _.omit(yourObject, proptoDelete)
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `strictNullChecks` to false in tsconfig.json to disable this behavior:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strictNullChecks": false
  }
}
```