# The operand of a 'delete' operator must be optional.ts(2790) While creating a form using Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I don't understand why this error happening.
I'm creating a form to submit user email

```
export const register = createAsyncThunk<
  User,
  RegisterProps,
  {
    rejectValue: ValidationErrors;
  }
>("auth/registerStatus", async (credentials, { rejectWithValue }) => {
  try {
    // Don't POST blank email
    if (!credentials["email"]) {
      delete credentials["email"]; //editor marking in this line there is error.
    }
    const response = await api.post(API_REGISTER, credentials);
    return response.data;
  } catch (err) {
    const error: AxiosError<ValidationErrors> = err;
    if (!error.response) {
      throw err;
    }
    return rejectWithValue(error.response.data);
  }
});
```

but I am facing this error:

> The operand of a 'delete' operator must be optional.ts(2790)

I guess there is some logic error but I need your help to solve this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what is the logic behind error - the operand of a 'delete' operator must be optional typescript 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63702057/what-is-the-logic-behind-error-the-operand-of-a-delete-operator-must-be-opti)

Comment: In interface of `credentials` (`RegisterProps` I guess), `email` is a non optional property, hence you can't delete it. Make it an optional property in your inteface.

Comment: Don't use the `delete` operator on a property that is defined as a required property. Show the definition of the `credentials` class or interface.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your `credentials` interface or class declaration object, you must mark `email` as option field using `?` mark.

ex:

```
    interface Credentials {
        email?: string,
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Another solution, we could use the `Partial` utility type to construct a new type with the properties set to optional before using the delete operator.

```
credentials: Partial<Credentials> = { ... };
delete credentials["email"];
```

Answer (score 4):

This error happens because you created a class with the mandatory attribute you can work around creating a mirror class with the optional attributes.

```
class Foo {
    aa: string
    bb: number
    cc: boolean
}

type FooMirror = {aa: string, bb?: number, cc?: boolean}

const foo = new Foo()

const test: FooMirror = foo

delete test.aa // error operator must by optional
delete test.bb // true
delete test.cc // true
```

Answer (score 3):

```
delete (credentials as any).email
```

Not very familiar with typescript, but I bumped into something similar and I solved this way

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disable this behavior, set `strictNullChecks` to false in tsconfig.json:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strictNullChecks": false
  }
}
```