# The operand of a 'delete' operator must be optional / Object is possibly 'undefined' error in angular 12

Tags: angular, typescript

SO I'm working in creating a alert service in angular and I'm unable to get past this error. I know this this error can be suppressed by disabling strict null check in ts.config file. But don't want to take that approach tried with the ***!*** operator to make it optional but it still didn't work im not sure if i am putting the operator at the right place ,I'm a newbie to angular any guidance will be very helpful thank you

```
 alerts: Alert[] = [];

 this.alerts!.find(x => x === alert).fade = true;
```

**alert.model.ts**

```
export class Alert {
   public id!: string;
   public type!: AlertType;
   public message!: string;
   public autoClose!: boolean;
   public keepAfterRouteChange!: boolean;
   public fade!: boolean;

    constructor(init?:Partial<Alert>) {
        Object.assign(this, init);
    }
}

export enum AlertType {
    Success,
    Error,
    Info,
    Warning
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try `this.alerts.find(x => x === alert)!.fade` and `public keepAfterRouteChange?: boolean;`

Comment: Hi @NadiaChibrikova thanks for the quick response that helped

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the logic behind the TypeScript error "The operand of a 'delete' operator must be optional"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63702057/what-is-the-logic-behind-the-typescript-error-the-operand-of-a-delete-operato)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two different errors, both connected to the TypeScript feature known as [strict null checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html).

### Deleting an explicitly required property

Before trying to fix an error we need to understand, what causes this error. Otherwise things can derail very quickly. Let's look at the first message:

> The operand of a 'delete' operator must be optional

TypeScript allows developers to describe a set of rules which it has to obey. It then checks the code according to these rules in order to make it more consistent and less error-prone.

We say "my object must have this property" by marking it as non-optional in the code:

```
export class Alert {
  public keepAfterRouteChange!: boolean;
```

Then we try to delete this property, explicitly breaking the rule described above:

```
delete x.keepAfterRouteChange
```

Instead, we should answer the question "is this property actually optional?" and either mark it as optional (by using a question mark in the declaration: `keepAfterRouteChange?: boolean`) or never delete it from an object. Just assign a `false` value instead:

```
x.keepAfterRouteChange = false
```

### Trying to access a property of `undefined`

The second message is

> Object is possibly 'undefined'

According to [the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) the find() method can return `undefined`:

> If no values satisfy the testing function, `undefined` is returned.

We can't access a `.fade` property of an undefined value. If strict null checking was turned off, we would get an error message in the runtime:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'fade' of undefined

Fortunately, TypeScript warns us that something fishy is going on before even launching the code. To make things less fishy, we have to check if the value we're looking for was actually found.

However, in this particular code there we already have the value we're trying to find and mutate. It is stored in the `value` variable:

```
this.alerts!.find(x => x === alert).fade = true;
```

So there is no need to search for a value at all, we can mutate the `alert` object itself:

```
alert.fade = true
```

### Use bang operator as less as possible

Using an exclamation mark for assuming a non-null value [is considered a bad practice](https://dev.to/tmaximini/typescript-bang-operator-considered-harmful-3hhi) and should be avoided. It makes no sense in a class declaration when strict null checking mode is turned on. So instead of

```
export class Alert {
  public id!: string;
  public type!: AlertType;
  public message!: string;
  public autoClose!: boolean;
  public keepAfterRouteChange!: boolean;
  public fade!: boolean;
```

you can just write it without exclamation marks:

```
export class Alert {
  public id: string;
  public type: AlertType;
  public message: string;
  public autoClose: boolean;
  public keepAfterRouteChange: boolean;
  public fade: boolean;
```

Also, instead of saying that a value presumably has to be found

```
this.alerts.find(myFunction)!.fade = true;
```

you should check if a value was actually found or not:

```
const fadingAlert = this.alerts.find(myFunction)
if (fadingAlert) {
  fadingAlert.fade = true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @enkryptor for the detailed explanation