# The operand of a 'delete' operator must be optional. in index.test.tsx

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, react-typescript

I am new at using TS, and now I am  running a test using jest on react/typescript and I have got this error from type script saying  `The operand of a 'delete' operator must be optional.` and I can't find a way to stop TS to stop yelling
I have tried

```
interface Thing {
  prop: string | undefined;
}
```

but it didn't work with jest and the test still failing because of this,
any suggestion on this please,
this is my code snippet

```
  it('mergeFirestoreData', () => {
    const returnValue = mergeFirestoreData(`/${collectionNames.PERMITS}/id`, new PermitCore(), new PermitSwarm());
    const finalReturn = new Permit();
    delete finalReturn['endPermitReason']; //The operand of a 'delete' operator must be optional.ts(2790)
    expect(returnValue).toEqual(finalReturn);
  });
```

Comment: As far as I can see ([playground](https://tsplay.dev/WJqnkm)) this works with either `name: T | undefined` _or_ `name: T`, so please give a [mre].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the logic behind the TypeScript error "The operand of a 'delete' operator must be optional"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63702057/what-is-the-logic-behind-the-typescript-error-the-operand-of-a-delete-operato)

Answer (score 0):

Whatever is returned by `new Permit()` has a type something like this:

```
{
  // other properties
  endPermitReason: unknown;
}
```

It's not optional and therefore cannot be deleted. You can make it optional by adding a `?` in the type/interface declaration.

like this:

```
{
  // other properties
  endPermitReason?: unknown;
}
```

If you didn't define these types then you'll have to assert `finalReturn` as a `Partial<ReturnType<new Permit()>>` (double check that syntax).